# Python/Selenium i keep getting error

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

here is my code without all the necessary drivers imported im trying to run this but i keep gettting

```
indentation error:
ps C:/user/asus/temp > python clickex1.py
  file "clickex1.py" line 25
    try:
```

is it possible can someone answer to my question, i would be really appriciated
also can someone check my code and try to make it better?

```
results = []
with open("al.txt") as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
       results.extend(line.strip().split(',')) 

x = random.choice(results)   

while True:
    driver = webdriver.firefox()
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.get(x)
    time.sleep(10)
       try:
            element = driver.find_element_by_id("vB_Editor_QR_iframe")
            found = element
       if found == False:       
            except NoSuchElementException:
            time.sleep(5)
       elif found == True:
            element.send_keys("example")
            time.sleep(60)
            driver.close()
```

Comment: please accept the answer if it solved your problem so that the question can be closed

Answer (score 2):

You get an error because your indentation is incorrect. The error is pretty self-explanatory. Also you have not used exception handling properly.

```
while True:
    driver = webdriver.firefox()
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.get(x)
    time.sleep(10)
       try:
            element = driver.find_element_by_id("vB_Editor_QR_iframe")
            found = element
       if found == False:       
            except NoSuchElementException:
            time.sleep(5)
       elif found == True:
            element.send_keys("example")
            time.sleep(60)
            driver.close()
```

**should be**

```
while True:
    driver = webdriver.firefox()
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.get(x)
    time.sleep(10)
    try:
        element = driver.find_element_by_id("vB_Editor_QR_iframe")
        found = element
        if found == False:       
            raise NoSuchElementException
        elif found == True:
            element.send_keys("example")
            time.sleep(60)
            driver.close()
    except NoSuchElementException:
            time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: then there is the problem which while True: because if element = False the script restarts itself

Comment: @FurkancanTürksoy Also, here I have assumed that the exception `NoSuchElementException` has already been defined. If not, you would get a `NameError` when you run it.

Comment: it is defined  and i get no error but the problem is when it can't find the element it restarts the script have any ideas why is that happening?

Comment: @FurkancanTürksoy yes that is because you have placed everything inside an infinite loop so whether an exception is raised or not, the loop would continue forever. Consider using the `break` keyword where you want to terminate the loop.